# GLTF file is not getting serve in GCP/app engine

Tags: reactjs, google-app-engine, gltf, app.yaml, serve

I'm using App engine and deploying react app. I'm trying to serve `GTLF` files but it's not able locate them. It's in public folder I think I'm specifying the path correctly from `yaml` file. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

It is working perfectly on localhost.

Is there anything else I'm missing?

```
runtime: nodejs20
env: standard
service: default
 
handlers:
- url: /static
static_dir: build/static

- url: /(.*\.(json|ico|js))$
static_files: build/\1
upload: build/.*\.(json|ico|js)$

- url: .*
static_files: build/index.html
upload: build/index.html

- url: /scene\.gltf
static_files: /scene.gltf
upload: /scene.gltf
mime_type: model/gltf+json
 
- url: /scene\.bin
static_files: /scene.bin
upload: /scene.bin
mime_type: application/octet-stream
```

I tried changing `mime_type`, tried using `glb` file but still App engine isn't able to locate that file.

Comment: Please make sure that the indentation is correct as per this [example](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/reference/app-yaml?tab=node.js#example). Also, can you check if this format from this [Github link](https://gist.github.com/jonobr1/a971655d122109c1e6af0981feec3758) would work?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the indentation is correct as per this [example](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/reference/app-yaml?tab=node.js#example). Also, check if this format from this [Github link](https://gist.github.com/jonobr1/a971655d122109c1e6af0981feec3758) would work.

Your code should look something like this:

```
- url: /(.*\.(gltf))$
  static_files: public/\1
  upload: .*\.(gltf)$
```

If the suggestion I provided didn't work out, I would suggest filing this as a bug through this [link](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) so that Google Cloud engineers could take a look at it. This doesn't have a specific ETA on this but you can keep track of its progress once the ticket has been created.

Comment: Thanks you more taking time out for answering this. I tried this but it didn't work so I just changed extention of GLTF file and replace it with .json it worked. I don't why but it worked . Thanks anyways .